# While loop displays table results side by side

Tags: php, css

I am trying to display users' proclomations from database in their profile page. It was working perfectly untill I realized there was a styling bug. I fixed it yesterday but now results are showing side by side instead of one after another like normal tables. I don't know where is the problem.

This is what I mean: https://ibb.co/njn7DLq

```php
<div class="tableHorizontal">
        <?php
            $uid = $user['id'];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM proc WHERE uid = $uid ORDER BY proc_id DESC";
            $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

            if($num_rows == 0){
                echo "<div class='error-alert'><p>There is no any results!</p><div>";
              }else{
        ?>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th style="display:none;">ProcID</th>
                <th>From</th>
                <th>Where</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Currency</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Info</th>
                <th>Capacity</th>
                <th>Action</th><br>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                $results_per_page = 10;
                $num_of_pages = ceil($num_rows/$results_per_page);
                if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
                    $page = 1;
                    // header("profile.php?page=1");
                    echo "<script> window.location = 'profile.php?page=1' </script>";
                  }else{
                    $page = $_GET['page'];
                  }
                  $page_first_result = ((float)$page - 1.0)*$results_per_page;

                  $sql = "SELECT * FROM proc WHERE uid = $uid ORDER BY proc_id DESC LIMIT " . $page_first_result . " , " . $results_per_page . " ";
                    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                        ?> 
                        <td style="display:none;"><?= $rows['proc_id'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $rows['p_from'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $rows['p_where'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $rows['p_date'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $rows['price'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $rows['currency'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $rows['type'] ?></td>
                        <td id="info"><?= $rows['info'] ?></td>
                        <td><?= $rows['capacity'] ?> kg</td>
                        <td><a class="icon" onclick="delete_proc('<?= $rows['proc_id'] ?>');"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="update" onclick="update_proc('<?= $rows['proc_id'] ?>')"><i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                        <?php
                    } // End of while loop
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
<ul id="pagination" style="list-style-type: none;">
        <?php
        //display the links to the pages  
         for ($page=1; $page <= $num_of_pages; $page++) { 
          echo '<li class="page-item" style="display: inline; width:30px;"><a class="page-link" href="profile.php?page=' .$page.'" style="margin-top:-70px; background-color:white; color:black;">' . $page . '</a></li> ';
         } ?>
         </ul>
          <?php  }   ?>
```

And I only have this much of CSS to have horizontal scroll bar if screen is not wide enough to display the results.

```css
.tableHorizontal{
    overflow-x: auto;
    width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: You should have some `<tr>` tags around each line - so inside your `while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array(...` loop.

Answer (score 1):

your loop should be like following

```
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
 ?>
  <tr>
    <td style="display:none;"><?= $rows['proc_id'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $rows['p_from'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $rows['p_where'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $rows['p_date'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $rows['price'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $rows['currency'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $rows['type'] ?></td>
    <td id="info"><?= $rows['info'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $rows['capacity'] ?> kg</td>
    <td><a class="icon" onclick="delete_proc('<?= $rows['proc_id'] ?>');"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="update" onclick="update_proc('<?= $rows['proc_id'] ?>')"><i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
   </tr>
 <?php
}
```

Comment: Exactly! Can't believe I couldn't see such a little issue. Thanks a lot!